# It possible to query/convert LONG RAW (SDEBINARY) from SQL?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, st-geometry, oracle-spatial

Curently we have ArcSDE 9.3/Oracle10, and layers in SDEBINARY.

It is possible to make queries with SDE.ST_GEOMETRY or SDO_GEOMETRY commands ?

Comment: This might help: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2291&t=293241

Answer (score 1):

With ST_GEOMETRY and SDO_GEOMETRY  you can use SQL in addition to ArcGIS Desktop to work with your data. Although with SQL, one should take many precautions (read the docs).

To migrate from sde_binary to one of above, you have to reload all data into your database.

[Migrate Storage (Data Management)](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=1732&pid=1728&topicname=Migrate_Storage_(Data_Management))